# php array foreach loop skipping a single key value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to get a foreach loop to display all the values of an array but for some reason it skips value 4.

```
echo $sku."<br>";
$skuArray = explode(" ", $sku);
$skuCount = array_count_values($skuArray);
print_r($skuArray);
echo "<br><br>";
$i=0;
foreach ($skuCount as $key => $val) {
    echo "[".$i."] => ".$key." ";
    $i++;
}
```

and this is what the output looks like:

```
1DALI0SPBA775RW 2 $92.99 1GJESSGRIP10000 2 $9.99

Array ( [0] => 1DALI0SPBA775RW 
        [1] => 2 
        [2] => $92.99 
        [3] => 1GJESSGRIP10000 
        [4] => 2 
        [5] => $9.99 )

[0] => 1DALI0SPBA775RW 
[1] => 2 
[2] => $92.99 
[3] => 1GJESSGRIP10000 
[4] => $9.99
```

As you can see, the foreach loop says that 4 is equal to $9.99 but in the print_r array it is equal to 2 - which is what I expect it to be.

Comment: `array_count_values` sums the number of times a particular element appears in the array.

Comment: The issue is your foreach is looking at skuCount, why not do your foreach on skyuArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
echo $sku."<br>";
$skuArray = explode(" ", $sku);
print_r($skuArray);
echo "<br><br>";
$i=0;
foreach ($skuArray as $key => $val) {
    echo "[".$key."] => ".$val." ";
}
```

`array_count_values($skuArray)` actually creates an array you can loop through, but with duplicates elided to a single value.  See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).